# Android wear Phone requirement

Tags: android, wear-os

For Android wear I'm confused are you required to have a android phone or is it a option basically is it an accessory or a standalone device thank you

**Update**
Sorry just realized only ***programming*** questions can be asked on this website

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the hardware and not how to program for it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right - this question is some what out of focus - but I think that this question  bothers some people anyways ;-)

According to the announcements made at Google I/O 2014, technically speaking, any Wear-device is a stand-alone device: It can work without a connected phone and it can run its own applications (but they have to be installed by using a paired Android-phone).

But while the Wear-device is stand-alone you probably won't have much fun with it, when you don't pair it with a phone and use it as an accessory: without a network-connection, there won't be much you can do (except from showing the current time and how many steps you have taken).

Comment: And even then you shouldn't expect the time to stay accurate for very long.